# redirect user to other code if come from special link or site

Tags: php, redirect

If user come from special site or link show special code to him
like this

> s7efty*com/video/watch.php?vid=357dcc515

I want to redirect a user to an external site, outside of my php application, through The tricky part is, the user can enter the link himself.

if you click to watch now you will see the video embedded on another site

```
?hash=
```

but if open from other embed code will hidden

other example

> nsaem*net/videos/watch.php?vid=e7c95bbf4

Comment: This looks a lot like spam on first glance; can you edit your question to remove references to real URLs and videos?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed something under you special url use an HTML iframe.
Output in the iframes's src= your external url with PHP based on your special vid= variable

The user will stay in your page while using external content